# CSS IE6 float right

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, css-float, inline

How come when I have a div style at display: block; float: right, in IE6 the div still goes under the text, and not in the middle of it just floated to the right. It works in all other  browsers, including IE7+. I need to have display block because if i do display inline, then the menu inside the div is all messed up.

.content { 
display: block;
}

.float {
width: 150px;
display: block;
float: right;
}

.nothing {
display: inline;
}

the float class is not to the right of nothing class, its under it in IE6, know a fix?

---

I'm assuming this is what is meant:

```
<span>This is some text </span>

<div style="float: right;">
    This is floated text
</div>
```

The output is something like this:

```
This is some text    
                        This is floated text
```

If you float the span left, or

```
<span style="float:left;">This is some text </span>

<div style="float: right;">
    This is floated text
</div>
```

switch the order of the text and float

```
<div style="float: right;">
        This is floated text
</div>

<span>This is some text </span>
```

it works properly:

```
This is some text    This is floated text
```

Comment: Maybe you could include some HTML and accept your previous answers.

Comment: Maybe this belongs on doctype.com?

Comment: Already a similar issue on doctype: http://doctype.com/wierd-ie6-float-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the link Greg posted in a comment ([doctype.com/wierd-ie6-float-issue](http://doctype.com/wierd-ie6-float-issue)) for a working solution. Basically put you floating element first in the html.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an option in your case, but maybe you could try `float: left` with `align: right` in the parent element? This has worked for me in the past, but is not useful in every case.